# Trying to Parse the JSON file from API call (HTTPGet) but ParseJSON function in SSJS doesnt work

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, cloudpage, marketingcloudapi

I want to get attribute sets for an attribute group. So before I used an API call just for the attribute groups. And it worked. For this I make the API GET call and it is successful but I can not parse it. If I just put the response.content in a write function it displays but when I add the ParseJSON function I get the try catch block error. The JSON file is a bit large and for this code I get "invalid length" error.

1. This is the code.

   ```
    <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");
    try {
    var authEndpoint = 
    'https://mcx3g81x4fmdkj05rbw0jg9yb19m.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/';
    var payload = {
    client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    grant_type: "client_credentials" ,
    account_id: "xxxxxxxx"};
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
    var contentType = 'application/json'



    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, 
    Stringify(payload));
    //Write(accessTokenRequest.StatusCode);
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
    var tokenResponse = 
    Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
    var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
    var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url};
    var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

    var output = [];
    var page = 1;
    var pageSize = 50;
    var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + 
    "/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions?$page=" + page + "&$pageSize" 
    + pageSize;


    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(requestUrl);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.setHeader("Authorization",auth );
    req.method = "GET";
    req.encoding= "UTF-8"



   var resp = req.send();
   //Write(String(resp.content))
   var result = String(resp.content)
   var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result);
   Write(obj.items)






   // Check the response code
   if(resp.statusCode == 200) {


   //var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content))




   }



   } catch (error) {
   Write("ERRORBIG"+error);
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE (Salesforce StackExchange), Ronaldo. I don't know much yet about Marketing Cloud but can I suggest you to format the code in the post instead of sharing the screenshot?

Comment: Thanks I changed it.

Comment: Can you share what 'try...catch' error you see? Also have you validated that the returned content is in valid JSON format? Can check it here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The error I get is "invalid length".

Answer (score -3):

ParseJSON - Parses the supplied string or array value and returns a object from that value. This function will not execute functions within the supplied values. Try writing string function separately.

Comment: I tried that to but it doesn't work. It gives the same error.

Comment: Try writing a custom logic to get value of items from reposne.content.

Comment: I did but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: This is not running any functions inside of the ParseJSON and you can utilize multiple different nested capabilities and functions inside of ParseJSON - it will run based on the final result of the nested actions.

Comment: @Gortonington I'm not sure what you mean by your comment, but I tried the API request op posted and indeed it's not possible to correctly parse the resulting JSON. I tried with smaller page sizes, and then parsing works (eg. page size=5) but then each consecutive page gives the same results (starting from the beginning)

Comment: @zuzannamj - sorry my comment was in reaction to the answer here stating that ParseJSON cannot run functions or nested actions. It was not toward the actual OP question. I did not have a chance to dive into the issue, I was more trying to ensure there was no misunderstanding on capabilities of ParseJSON by this answer.